# Temp table in different database

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can a temp table be created in another database with `sql server 2005?` I know that when temp tables are created, they go to tempdb and will be automatically be dropped. My question is can I create it in a different database, if so, how?

Comment: you can create a table anywhere you like....tmpMyTable

Comment: not just a table but a temp table.. #temptable

Comment: a temp table IS just a table!

Answer (score 0):

Sql server temporary tables (table names that start with #) cannot be created in any other database, they will always be created in tempdb database.

Comment: if you are looking for something to throw away without explicitly dropping it, then you can use table variables, but they come with their own pros/cons as well.